# Boron and diols

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

How does the Boron react with diol? Is this the right way it reacts? What kind of interaction is this?

Why does such a reaction occur?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your starting material (**1**) is 2,1-Benzoxaborol-1(*3H*)-ol. This can be considered as the intramolecular half-**ester** of 2-hydroxymethyl-phenylboronic acid.

[image]

Under suitable conditions, esterification of **1** with the diol will initially yield the ester **2**.

Transesterification, that is closing one five-membered ring while opening the other in this case, may lead to **3**.

Comment: That said, I do think that even very mildly basic conditions (e.g. aqueous bicarbonate) would suffice to quantitatively convert the mixture into the boronate anion shown in the question.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto You're probably right and I didn't think it though.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha In the absence of base 3 will be the preferred product? In the presence of base, would the tetrahedral product be as shown in my question or would it be 3 with an additional OH attached to B? I am a little confused about how the products are/will form.

Answer (score -3):

Boron is a Levis acid while he alcohol is considered a Levis base. It is able to have a reaction between them. The problem is that the structure of the product of reaction do not show a -OH group.

Comment: Why should the product have an OH group in it? Does the initial OH group attach leave as water?